# Unity3D - GUIText Does Not Show On Collision With Object

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine, character, unityscript

Ive been following [this](http://twcdc.com/andycox/art-and-technology/412-class-documents/making-text-appear-on-the-screen-near-an-object/) article online and have swapped a few names and tags about but I dont seem to see any text appearing on the screen...

Here is my `PlayerCollision` script:

```
#pragma strict

function Update () {

}

function OnControllerColliderHit(hit : ControllerColliderHit){
    if(hit.gameObject.tag == "Collider"){
        ShowMessage.message = "HELLO WORLD";
        ShowMessage.turnTextOn = true;
    }
}
```

This is my `ShowMessage` script:

```
#pragma strict

static var turnTextOn : boolean = false;
static var message : String;
private var timer : float = 0.0;

function Start(){
    timer = 0.0;
    turnTextOn = false;
    guiText.text = "";
}

function Update () {
    if(turnTextOn){
        guiText.enabled = true;
        guiText.text = message;
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if(timer >= 5){
        turnTextOn = false;
        guiText.enabled = false;
        timer = 0.0;
    }
}
```

I have linked the ShowMessage script to my GUIText object and have linked the `PlayerCollision` script with the `CharacterController`. There is also a box collider object with the `Collision` tag I also Have the GUIText in view just to rule that out.

Anyone any idea what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: inside your if statement in OnControllerColliderHit put a print("hit"); to see if it is actually being triggered

Comment: Did you tag the object your colliding with as "Collider"?

Comment: You also have to add a `Box Collider` on the tagged object

Answer (score 0):

The tag should be `"Collider"` not `"Collision"` because `if(hit.gameObject.tag == "Collider")`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turns out I ticked `isTrigger` which stopped the collision from being detected. This gives the problem of the character not being able to move through the object. What i did was tick the `isTrigger` option and change `OnControllerColliderHit(hit : ControllerColliderHit)` to `OnTriggerEnter (obj : Collider)`